# Single file bundle with NestJS + Typescript + Webpack + node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, nestjs

How? How I can bundle NestJS project including node_module for offline application?

#### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/main.js'),
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    filename: 'compiled.js',
    path: __dirname,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      node_modules: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    },
    extensions: ['.js'],
  },
};
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "kai-brs",
  "version": "0.9.1",
  "author": "Sovgut Sergey",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build:webpack": "rimraf dist && tsc -p tsconfig.build.json && webpack dist/main.js -o dist/main.bundle.js --mode=production",
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.build.json",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts",
    "start:dev": "nodemon",
    "start:debug": "nodemon --config nodemon-debug.json",
    "prestart:prod": "rimraf dist && npm run build",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main.js",
    "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^6.0.5",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/dotenv": "^6.1.1",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.4.8",
    "dotenv": "^7.0.0",
    "graphql": "^14.2.1",
    "graphql-tools": "^4.0.4",
    "joi": "^14.3.1",
    "mssql": "^5.0.5",
    "multer": "^1.4.1",
    "public-ip": "^3.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "screenshot-desktop": "^1.7.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.16",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/testing": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.1",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.13",
    "@types/joi": "^14.3.2",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.7",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "prettier": "^1.15.3",
    "supertest": "^3.4.1",
    "ts-jest": "^23.10.5",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.7.0",
    "tslint": "5.12.1",
    "typescript": "^3.2.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

## Now I have this errors :(

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/public-ip/node_modules/got/source/request-as-event-emitter.js 72:18-25
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
 @ ./node_modules/public-ip/node_modules/got/source/as-promise.js
 @ ./node_modules/public-ip/node_modules/got/source/create.js
 @ ./node_modules/public-ip/node_modules/got/source/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/public-ip/index.js
 @ ./dist/service/illumenator.service.js
 @ ./dist/service/illumenator.module.js
 @ ./dist/service.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js 107:27-40
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/index.js
 @ ./dist/server.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js 112:23-85
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/index.js
 @ ./dist/server.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/utils/load-package.util.js 8:39-59
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/serializer/class-serializer.interceptor.js
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/serializer/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/index.js
 @ ./dist/service.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/app-root-path/lib/app-root-path.js 14:10-56
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/app-root-path/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/index.js
 @ ./dist/server.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/parse5/lib/index.js 55:23-49
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/cli-highlight/dist/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/index.js
 @ ./dist/server.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 81:13-25
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/adapters/express-adapter.js
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/adapters/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/index.js
 @ ./dist/service/illumenator.controller.js
 @ ./dist/service/illumenator.module.js
 @ ./dist/service.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/@nestjs/core/helpers/load-adapter.js 8:39-63
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-factory.js
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/core/index.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/optional/optional.js 6:11-26
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/core/index.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/keyv/src/index.js 18:14-40
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/cacheable-request/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/public-ip/node_modules/got/source/request-as-event-emitter.js
 @ ./node_modules/public-ip/node_modules/got/source/as-promise.js
 @ ./node_modules/public-ip/node_modules/got/source/create.js
 @ ./node_modules/public-ip/node_modules/got/source/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/public-ip/index.js
 @ ./dist/service/illumenator.service.js
 @ ./dist/service/illumenator.module.js
 @ ./dist/service.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ioredis' in 'c:\Users\Essential\Documents\kai-brs\node_modules\typeorm\platform'
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/index.js
 @ ./dist/server.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mongodb' in 'c:\Users\Essential\Documents\kai-brs\node_modules\typeorm\platform'
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/index.js
 @ ./dist/server.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mysql' in 'c:\Users\Essential\Documents\kai-brs\node_modules\typeorm\platform'
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/index.js
 @ ./dist/server.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mysql2' in 'c:\Users\Essential\Documents\kai-brs\node_modules\typeorm\platform'
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/index.js
 @ ./dist/server.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'oracledb' in 'c:\Users\Essential\Documents\kai-brs\node_modules\typeorm\platform'
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/index.js
 @ ./dist/server.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pg' in 'c:\Users\Essential\Documents\kai-brs\node_modules\typeorm\platform'
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/index.js
 @ ./dist/server.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pg-native' in 'c:\Users\Essential\Documents\kai-brs\node_modules\typeorm\platform'
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/index.js
 @ ./dist/server.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pg-query-stream' in 'c:\Users\Essential\Documents\kai-brs\node_modules\typeorm\platform'
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/index.js
 @ ./dist/server.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/typeorm/driver/react-native/ReactNativeDriver.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native-sqlite-storage' in 'c:\Users\Essential\Documents\kai-brs\node_modules\typeorm\driver\react-native'
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/driver/react-native/ReactNativeDriver.js
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/driver/DriverFactory.js
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/connection/Connection.js
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/connection/ConnectionManager.js
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/index.js
 @ ./dist/server.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'redis' in 'c:\Users\Essential\Documents\kai-brs\node_modules\typeorm\platform'
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/index.js
 @ ./dist/server.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sql.js' in 'c:\Users\Essential\Documents\kai-brs\node_modules\typeorm\platform'
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/index.js
 @ ./dist/server.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

WARNING in ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sqlite3' in 'c:\Users\Essential\Documents\kai-brs\node_modules\typeorm\platform'
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
 @ ./node_modules/typeorm/index.js
 @ ./dist/server.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-factory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@nestjs/microservices' in 'c:\Users\Essential\Documents\kai-brs\node_modules\@nestjs\core'
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-factory.js 41:115-147
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/core/index.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@nestjs/microservices' in 'c:\Users\Essential\Documents\kai-brs\node_modules\@nestjs\core'
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js 101:115-147
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/core/index.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/cache/cache.providers.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cache-manager' in 'c:\Users\Essential\Documents\kai-brs\node_modules\@nestjs\common\cache'
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/cache/cache.providers.js 10:103-127
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/cache/cache.module.js
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/cache/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/index.js
 @ ./dist/service.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/validation.pipe.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'class-transformer' in 'c:\Users\Essential\Documents\kai-brs\node_modules\@nestjs\common\pipes'
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/validation.pipe.js 43:104-132
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/index.js
 @ ./dist/service.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/serializer/class-serializer.interceptor.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'class-transformer' in 'c:\Users\Essential\Documents\kai-brs\node_modules\@nestjs\common\serializer'
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/serializer/class-serializer.interceptor.js 28:116-144 29:8-36
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/serializer/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/index.js
 @ ./dist/service.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/validation.pipe.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'class-validator' in 'c:\Users\Essential\Documents\kai-brs\node_modules\@nestjs\common\pipes'
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/validation.pipe.js 42:100-126
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/index.js
 @ ./dist/service.module.js
 @ ./dist/main.js
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! kai-brs@0.9.1 build:webpack: `rimraf dist && tsc -p tsconfig.build.json && webpack dist/main.js -o dist/main.bundle.js --mode=production`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the kai-brs@0.9.1 build:webpack script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Essential\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-09T09_19_07_825Z-debug.log
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 2
```

*Or tell me a good framework for developing **windows service on node.js** which has scaffold and **builds into a single file**. (it is imperative that the assembly includes all dependencies, that is, the entire node_modules folder, because the PCs to which this service will be installed **does not have Internet** for using `npm`)*

Comment: hej, I have the same problem. I want to build my application with all it's dependencies .  Have you found the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work with the following `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const WebPackIgnorePlugin =
{
  checkResource: function(resource)
  {
    const lazyImports =
    [
        '@nestjs/microservices',
        '@nestjs/microservices/microservices-module',
        'cache-manager',
        'class-transformer',
        'class-validator',
        'fastify-static',
    ];
  
    if (!lazyImports.includes(resource))
      return false;

    try
    {
      require.resolve(resource);
    }
    catch (err)
    {
      return true;
    }
  
    return false;
  }
};

module.exports =
{
  mode: 'production',
  target: 'node',
  entry:
  {
    server: './src/main.ts',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module:
  {
    rules:
    [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve:
  {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
  },
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
  },
  plugins:
  [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(WebPackIgnorePlugin),
  ],
  optimization:
  {
    minimize: false
  },
  performance:
  {
    maxEntrypointSize: 1000000000,
    maxAssetSize: 1000000000
  },
  output:
  {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'prod'),
  },
};
```

The part you need to pay attention to here is the `IgnorePlugin`. Nest uses lazy loading for some modules, and webpack can't tell which ones. The `checkResource()` makes the necessary checks for those modules that eould otherwise generate errors when trying to bundle your code.

You also need to put the `target: node` option in your config so that webpack knows some modules like `fs` and `net` are supported natively in Node (which is not the case when the target is a browser).

Answer (score 1):

@SergeySovgut: I am not sure if you have managed to add the custom configuration using webpack, yet. But here is one that I use currently in my prj

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
var terserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
var uglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
var dotEnvPlugin = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = function(options) {
    return {
        ...options,
        entry: [ './src/main.ts'],
        watch: false,
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.jade']
        },
        externals: [
            nodeExternals(),
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [
                ...options.module.rules,
                {
                    test: /\.handlebars$/,
                    loader: 'handlebars-loader',
                    options: {
                        knownHelpersOnly: false,
                        inlineRequires: /\/assets\/(:?images|audio|video)\//ig,
                        partialDirs: [path.join(__dirname, './src/views/email/partials')],
                    },
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            ...options.plugins,
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
            new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin([/\.js$/, /\.d\.ts$/]),
            new dotEnvPlugin({
                path: './config/development/.env',
                safe: true,
                systemvars: true,
                silent: true,
                defaults: false
            }), new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': 'dev',
                'process.env.DEBUG': 'debug'
            }),new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin([/\.js$/, /\.d\.ts$/]),
        ],
    };
};
```

In short, nest comes packed with webpack. Some of the rules have been preset, so for example, ts-loader has been autoconfigured to transpile your .ts to .js files. So all we need to do is extend the options already provided by nestjs and then write our custom configuration on top of it.

I believe most of the configurations are straightforward and could be easily obtained via the webpack docs

To run the file, configure a script like this
->  `"build:webpack:dev": "rimraf dist && nest build --watch --webpack  webpack.dev.config.js"

Then run `npm run build:webpack:dev`

More details [here from official docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/hot-reload#configuration-1)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I write a simple demo base on the nestjs typescript-starter:

https://github.com/suhaotian/nestjs-starter-bundle-single-file

Very simple:

package.json scripts add:

```
"build": "npx tsdk --nest build",
```

Run `npm run build`, you will see `dist-projects` folder